# When should you consider using time series in analysis?

Tags: time-series

I have a number of projects that I am working on where data is collected over time periods of months to years. My first question is when should time be considered as a factor in conducting analyses and tests on the data?

E.g. I have a list of 100 individual products and track view and purchase events which occur infrequently over a period of 3 months. I wish to compare the ratio of views to purchases to see if one product is purchased more frequently than another based on its popularity (views) then should I consider time as a factor in this analysis?

My second question is what is the best test to use to check for difference between ratio of views and purchases of these products?

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: One important thing to remember in time series analysis, is that in time series analysis, not only the ordering of when the observations occur matter, but also the time interval/frequency have to be the same. That is, you cannot mix daily/weekly/monthly data.

Comment: That is not correct @fredrikhs , although many time series methods require equal intervals, not all do. I am not expert on this, but have seen it.

Comment: Thank you correcting me, I will take it up with my professors. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I wish to compare the ratio of views to purchases to see if one product is purchased more frequently than another based on its popularity (views)...

One way to phrase this question is, "Does the number of views of a product *x* at time *t* influence the number of units sold *y* at time *t*?" If this is your research question, then the answer to your first question is "probably". Think about it: purchases are growing over time. So are views. Does the growth of units sold differ as a function of the growth of views? A latent growth curve analysis with time-varying covariates would help you answer this. Do a search for that.

As for your second question (and your several references to the ratio of view to purchases), I say this: What you are after is the relationships between views and purchases, not the ratio. So look for ways to model purchases as a function of views. I gave one suggestion above.

Comment: @Rodule: How's it goin'?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly need to consider time, but longitudinal analysis is broader than just time series - there are multi-level models and generalized estimating equations and so on. But, given your problem, I think the best approach might be survival analysis with multiple events. This is a pretty complex area, but there are some good books e.g. [Therneau & Grambsch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387987843). But if you haven't studied survival analysis, that book will be diving in the very deep end indeed. You could start with this little book by [Allison](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0803920555) as a very introductory level start.